# Why are error codes on websites shown as "404 Not Found"

Tags: error-message, errors

Most error pages on websites display http status codes in messages.
Eg - "404 Not Found"

**Is that status code really helpful for a user?**

[image]

A previous question asked [Are HTTP error codes user-friendly?](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/33222/are-http-error-codes-user-friendly). However, that question refers to a default error page for a web server. Here, I am asking about error pages that are designed by web a designer/developer in a production site.

Comment: @DA01 I don't think so: This question is about showing the code, that one is about showing a 404 document altogether.

Comment: Status codes have the major advantage of being language-independent and not needing translation.

Comment: So the 404 was not found? Then what am I looking at?

Answer (score 16):

404 and 500 are most common error codes and 404 is the most famous one. If your target audience have exposure to computer as educational basis or a mid level surfer he/she will understand as what 404 means and not much of other status codes. Still it is not a good practice to display error codes as only or prominent way of communicating technical problem/status to user. You can display the status code with less weight in the screen which is not prominent than the user friendly status message, so that the user can quote it to explain to the support executive of your website.

Comment: Speaking as a former technical support person turned web developer/designer, the status codes really help! Some people write the entire error code on a piece of paper before they call support. Better to hear "I have this thing on the screen that is a 404 error" as opposed to "IT'S NOT WORKING".

Comment: Daryll, from a customer perspective perhaps. From a hacker perspective, leaking error codes (in general) will give them information about your system. Will HTTP error codes leak information? Probably not so much. But codes in general will.

Comment: I disagree @corsiKa - because most "real world" applications have custom error codes, they don't just pop up the system default error code (or message). This way, when it comes to troubleshooting the error is easier to resolve because the code has special meaning for technical support.  Hackers knowing you custom error codes and messages will not help them.

Comment: If you generate a 1 time code, for example "tell support this is regarding incident 31456" then they gain nothing. If you tell them more, you most certainly risk leaking information about what systems, libraries, and dependencies you are running (thereby giving them potential avenues of attack). "Oh, a Catalina error? Let's see if they're running a version where flaw ____ wasn't patched yet and i can elevate to root access..." Nothing you would tell the user isn't also available in the logs, which support has to check anyway. There's no reason to tell the user anything than "go call support".

Comment: The HTTP error code will *not* give information to a hacker about systems and libraries on the server.
Providing excessive information on the error page might, and certainly should be avoided, but `404` and `500` give no such information.

Comment: I'd like to point out these codes come from the web server as part of the HTTP request. Any hacker worth their salt could easily get the HTTP status code, even if it's not displayed on the page.

Comment: It may not always be so obvious though. For example, the GitHub API, on receiving a request for a private repository, returns a "page not found" error instead of a "permission denied" error, because the latter would certify that the private repository exists. You have to be careful in these situations.

Comment: @Dancrumb Information is information, a `403` vs `404` error for example indicates whether or not a file exists on the server. I agree that it is not particularly dangerous information, but the entire point of having a HTTP status code is to give information (otherwise why bother having them?).

Comment: @Luke, information may be information, but an HTTP status code does not provide information about systems or libraries on the server (which is what I said). It provides information about the server's ability to process a request... and very limited information at that.

Comment: @Luke: Yes, it is an information - but as so often, there is a balance between keeping something safe and keeping it usable. What you are describing is not a one-way road, along the lines of "the less information, the better": Whether a request returned `403` or `404` is not only a piece of information that could possibly be abused, it is at the same time a valuable piece of information for a user. In some contexts, the user needs/wants to know whether they mistyped their credentials (`403`) or the target URL (`404`), and hiding that could thus deteriorate user experience in that case.

Comment: @Luke: On a broader sense, that can probably be said about all such restrictions; including what corsiKa pointed out. A banking website that doesn't provide any hints that it is a banking website draws probably much less attention to itself by possible attackers than one that does, but hiding that information also makes the site less useful for legitimate users.

Answer (score 12):

Error information should be tailored to the audience that needs to take action on the error.

- If it is the user, the user needs to get a user-friendly or at least
  user-understandable accounting of what the error is and what is
  expected of him. Nobody would expect ALL users to know what "404"
  means.
- If it is the systems administrator, or the network people, or anyone
  responsible for the infrastructure, an error code like "404" is
  precise, concise, and unambiguous. Here the expectation is the opposite, namely that the exact code "404" (and not say "410" which is the status "gone" and is different from the status "not found") is useful.

The problem is that 404 is in a grey area. 404 is not produced by the site, it is produced by the web server. Developers and systems administrators need this information, so showing it is crucial. However users might also get such a page if they enter a wrong address, so including a user-friendly explanation is also important. That's why most commercial websites who target users from the public at large will include both.

Comment: +1 for mentioning how to mix easy-to-use and precise+concise for different users, but honestly your example ("404.1") confuses me a bit.

Comment: @AlexP I checked the spec and you are right, the codes are all integers. I've updated my answer based on your feedback.

Comment: 404 does *not* mean "there is no site": it means "the page you asked for doesn't exist." That's precisely why 404 is useful: it's clear and unambiguous, rather than somebody's inaccurate attempt to describe what the problem was.

Comment: @DavidRicherby You are right, that sentence from my answer was not well formulated. I've updated the answer based on your feedback.

Comment: While 404 and 410 are different status codes, they might be treated the same by the client (for example, I believe Google's web crawler treats them identically).

Comment: Who says 404 is produced by the server rather than the site? Lots of sites will produce their own 404s, especially ones that use a lot of SEO slugs or have REST APIs or other complex routing rules. `/products/hammers` may be a valid page whereas `/products/kittens` may not. Only the site/application knows this, the underlying server infrastructure has no idea. It seems irrelevant regardless; *every* possible error is important to system administrators, and *every* possible error should probably result in a page that isn't a dead-end for users.

Comment: @Aaronaught technically I agree with you of course, but the distinction I was trying to develop in my answer is that between site-related errors (e.g. you cannot refund a purchase if the payment has not been received, which is only relevant to a user and only the user can solve it) and infrastructure related errors like a 404 (that the user may detect but user and infrastructure support action might be needed to correct.)

Comment: @Aaronaught - you're right that the website's developers define how the page looks, but what those people mean is that the server *generates* the error code, then loads webpage.com/404 instead, for example.

Comment: @OllieFord: If you're saying what I think you're saying... *redirecting* to a static 404 page is extremely bad practice. You immediately lose all context, so it's impossible to try to help the user find a *similar* or *relevant* page based on other signals in the URL. And it's not possible for the user or a tester to report the error (sure, you're awesome and automatically log and track 404s... you still don't always know *how they got there*). There's no meaningful distinction between "site" and "server" - each one can be responsibility for "generating" the error or "displaying" it or both.

Comment: @Aaronaught That was an arbitrary example (and besides, it being static doesn't mean that information is lost) - there is a distinction. If you try to access a page, a file on the server, which doesn't exist, it generates the 404. The website's developer(s) define what the outcome is beyond that. They don't have to make it display anything at all, it could be some random page, the home page, redirect to ux.stack - anything.

Comment: @OllieFord: Once again, that was true maybe 15 years ago. In almost every modern application, the developers decide how to route various URLs and thus it is up to the developers, via the application code, to decide which "pages" or "files" actually exist. For example, it's perfectly reasonable and normal, for security reasons, to return a 404 for a resource that technically exists, but which the user simply doesn't have access to. The distinction you imagine simply is not there. The decision about whether or not to return a 404 and what to do about can literally be on 2 consecutive lines.

Answer (score 4):

Like others have stated. There's nothing wrong with a 404 since it's practically common knowledge. It refers to a page not found.

Though you shouldn't show the default 404 page to a user, but rather design your own. And specifically add the text 'Page not found, so it's obvious for any users that are *ahem* not from this planet.

Great example: http://gchen.cn/blog/2014/09/01/blog-recover

**EDIT:**

[image: 404]

Answer (score 3):

Generally, no, status codes are not the best thing to display to an end user.  However, 404 entered the vernacular a long time ago, before such best practices were common, and enough people learned it that it's managed to stick around.

Comment: I frequently see a 500 error presented as simply "Internal Error", without any mention of the "500". I regard that as poor practice, because people have a tendency to rephrase or misremember error messages, sometimes turning them into something else! (a _different_ error message). A numeric code is much less likely to mutate when someone is reporting an error.

Comment: @PhilPerry, Not that "hey you got a 500 error" is especially useful... =/

Comment: "hey you got a 500 error" would _not_ be useful. "You have a 500 (Internal Server) error" _would_ be useful, which is what I was calling for. A user may muck up the text of the message, but is unlikely to turn 500 into 404. It's a bit of redundancy for a noisy communications channel.

Comment: While we're chatting about this, I've got to mention my pet peeve about the (default?) Apache setup. If you don't have a custom error page for a given error, Apache reports not only the (default message) for the error, but also a 404 for the "missing" error page. I see an incredible number of reports titled "I'm getting a 404 error" which upon deeper digging, turn out to be other errors. 500 errors where no number is given are especially bad, as people often leave out all mention of "Internal server error".

Comment: @PhilPerry: Actually, *why* is a message like "You have a 500 (Internal Server) error" more useful than "You have a 500 error" (assuming in both cases that users correctly interpret the *500* as the error code, or rephrasing the sentences to make that clearer)? Wouldn't users rather be put off by the "technical jargon" ("internal server")? If chances are that part of the message is going to be misremembered and the error code is everything support needs to know, why is the error code name necessary, as well?

Comment: @O.R.Mapper, you don't want to have a bunch of technical jargon that could confuse users, but it's still useful for most users to know it's likely _not_ something _they_ did to cause this error. Saying "internal server" isn't likely to cause panic, and could be useful for more advanced users.

Comment: @PhilPerry: Yes, it is. Users that are somehow likely to think they did something wrong will probably interpret "internal server error" as "Oh shoot. I damaged their internal server." I can easily see that lead to the *opposite* of what was intended, namely that they specifically refrain from contacting anyone about the issue for fear of having to pay for damaging the server. My point is that for less tech-savvy users, the text "internal server error" doesn't make it clear at all *who* caused the error or what happened, not even approximately.

Comment: Then why give _any_ error code, much less a message? Just say "Oops, our bad. Something went wrong." and hope that all the required information is logged. Dumb users will _still_ think they did something wrong, I guess. It's like children hiding in a closet after they've accidentally started a fire, afraid of punishment.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is going against the advice of other commenter's for this question, but I'd **strongly** advise against showing any stack, trace or other diagnostic messages on an error page. This is known as "information leakage" - to a regular user of the site the best thing you can say about it is that its little more than clutter on the page, at worst it's a source of confusion. More importantly this information can be used by a potential attacker to hack your site.

This sort of information is worth recording, a log file is probably the best place for it.

Comment: So are you saying showing the 404 code is information leakage or are you referring to the actual debug info that some people forget to suppress?  I don't think showing the error code would be considered information leakage. Google does it: http://www.google.com/foo.

Comment: @CodeMaverick, I don't think a HTML error code would constitute the same level of information leakage as - say - a stack trace. In Rails, Sinatra and Django applications you can get a complete stack trace of the issue, with code snippets, if you leave debug enabled. It's this kind of information that is being referred to in this answer.

Comment: @JimmyThompson - I agree, I was just wanting *Stormcloud* to clarify.

Comment: So how much information is _too much_ (of more value to a hacker than to diagnosing the problem)? I would think you would need (in addition to HTTP status/error code, and message) the full URL. Anything else? Is it practical to try to log any additional diagnostic information (especially if there are numerous errors, or the database is down, or the filesystem is full, or ...)?

Comment: @PhilPerry That kind of diagnostic information sounds like it's best logged to the server, not shown to the user.

Comment: If nothing else, as a courtesy to the user, they need to know if _they_ caused the problem (e.g., requested a non-existent page) and/or might be able to fix it in some manner, or if it's a system problem they can do nothing about. They also might like to know if there's a time estimate for it to be resolved ("Our system is very heavily loaded. Please try again later."). If you're pretty sure all diagnostic information can usually be logged, that could be enough.

Comment: Sorry I've obviously not been clear enough. One of the answers on this page suggested displaying "status or error codes plus additional details like stack traces" and I think this bad advice.

I've no problem with "Error 404" (although I do like so see that message replace by something a bit more intuitive), after all the server has to display something. *Stack Traces* on the other hand are of no value to the general user and they do disclose information about the implementing environment. This is the 'I' in the STRIDE security model....

Comment: ...For example, if I was an attacker and saw a stack trace I could quickly work out which version of the web server is being used to hosting a site and then a quick web search would tell me which known vunerabilities could be used to attack it. The sad thing is that many web servers display stack traces by default. While this is handy for developers, it is not acceptable for a general deployment (personally I'd include internal system in this as well). Display a 404 error if the page doesn't exist or a 503 if a backend system has failed. Send all of the stack traces to a log file.

Answer (score 2):

Many sites pay special attention on "code 404". Instead of boring messages, it is very refreshing for users to see some creative, witty page, like this [error 404 on car sale website](http://www.polovniautomobili.com/stranica-nije-pronadjena.html) that displays celebrated Peugeot 404.

[image: error 404 on car sale website]

Answer (score 0):

**For webapps and internal sites, I usually prefer to show both, a proper translation**, which explains the error and possibly provides additional guidance, **and the status or error codes** plus additional details like stack traces.

This is especially true, if the set of codes is limited, because in those cases, there tend to be not just short messages, but properly translated pages for all status and error codes. The problem with those, however, is that **translations are often not quite to the point, especially for technical, support or admin personnel, who actually form a second grouo of target users** for status and error pages. Translations are often abbreviating or short-circuiting things slightly, which tends to confuse techies not accustomed to the message. For them, **an actual code is very clear and typically undisputable**.

That's why I prefer to show both, albeit the more technical codes in smaller print with additional details typically only visible on demand.

Answer (score 0):

Error pages are a real nuisance in the gluteus maximus, butt you most certainly can use them to your advantage.

Don't do this:

[image]

Your beautifully crafted design and UX flow destroyed in mere milliseconds.

Instead, you could do this:

- Design error pages for the most common errors (404, 500, 403, ..?)
- Provide a short and simple description of what went wrong
- Add a 'back to previous page' button/link
- Add a search bar
- Add a sitemap
- Display random pictures of kittens

All in all, **let your users know something went wrong and then help them to fix it.**

Comment: OP is asking why we show the **error code**. Not about showing a themed page or not.

Comment: Obviously, your server should be able to handle code `418 I'm a Teapot`